# Vue grid layout error?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Im trying to use Vue Grid Layout: https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout
in my application (Using Vue2)

I have a "dashboard" component, where I want to use the grid layout, however getting errors when trying to import the files into the component - Im getting the error:

> Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. found in GridLayout

What im doing is importing the components and then registering them:

```
import GridLayout from 'vue-grid-layout';
import GridItem from 'vue-grid-layout';
```

And then registering :

```
components: {
      "GridLayout": GridLayout,
      "GridItem": GridItem
    }
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: I worked it out, had to do the following:

import VueGridLayout from 'vue-grid-layout';

  var GridLayout = VueGridLayout.GridLayout;
  var GridItem = VueGridLayout.GridItem;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to import two different named exports from that package. That requires a different syntax:

```
import { GridLayout } from 'vue-grid-layout';
import { GridItem } from 'vue-grid-layout';
```